# Fetch backbone collection fail from django-tastypie

Tags: backbone.js, render, fetch, tastypie

I'm using backbone-tastypie from https://github.com/PaulUithol/backbone-tastypie, and I can't fetch a collection data.
Thats my code:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/api/v1/user'
});


var HoraExtra = Backbone.Model.extend({
  url: '/api/v1/horasextra/'
});


var HorasExtra = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/v1/horasextra/',
  model: HoraExtra
});

var Horas = new HorasExtra();

var activeUser = new User();

var HorasExtraView = Backbone.View.extend({

initialize: function() {
  _.bindAll(this, "render");
},

render: function() {
  var plantilla = Handlebars.compile($("#horas_extra_template").html());
  var html = plantilla(Horas);
  this.$el.html(html);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(Horas));
  }
});

var HorasExtraWidget = new HorasExtraView({el: $('#base')});

Horas.fetch({
 data: {
    "usuario__id": 2,
    "hor_com__month": 11
  }
});

HorasExtraWidget.render();
```

And that's the result of console.log(JSON.stringify(Horas):

```
[]
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to you that you take tastypie, backbone and build your own simple project in 1-2 days.
Then you will get to know basic issues of coupling those 2 frameworks.
Without that knowledge it is pointless you try out other people's projects and then wonder "what isn't working".

And from my personal experience, both tastypie and javascript are pretty straightforward and are easy to couple.

And I am NOT an expert.

couple of points: try explicitly fetching models with fetch, manipulate fetched model from success callback, and watch your model url's, forward slashes in them etc.

Seems your collection is empty.

See in console if there is a GET call to server.
If not, you're not actually fetching anything from the server.

Answer (score 0):

I used https://github.com/amccloud/backbone-tastypie and then your code should look like this, I guess. Not tested.

```
var HorasCollection = Backbone.Tastypie.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/v1/horasextra/'
});

var HorasExtraView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#base'),
    entries: new HorasCollection(),
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.entries.fetch({
            success: function(entries){
                console.log("Entries", entries.models);
                // var t = _.template(template, {hello: 'world'});
                // that.$el.html(t);
            },
            error: function(model, response){
                console.log("Error", response);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

If you're trying to create a table for your data, try my jquery plugin :)
https://github.com/sspross/tastybackbonepie